# Sorting a group based on value

Tags: javascript, highcharts, mapreduce, crossfilter

> I have a group named p. On performing certain operations on this group, I get the corresponding output as shown-

```
p.all()
```

```
>> 01: {key: "A", value: {count:2}}
>> 102: {key: "B", value: {count:10}}
>> 103: {key: "C", value: {count:4}}
```

```
p5.all()[0].value.count
```

```
>> 2
```

```
p5.all()[1].value.count
```

```
>> 10
```

```
p5.all()[1].key
```

```
>> "B"
```

I want to sort the top 2 values based on the count. So that the output should be:

```
{key: "B", value: {count:10}}
{key: "C", value: {count:4}}
```

How can I sort it as such?

Comment: If you add the [javascript] tag you will get a lot of javascript answers. If you want crossfilter answers, better to leave off the much broader [javascript] tag. The crossfilter answer would be to use `.top()` and [`.order()`](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const myArray = [
  {key: "A", value: {count:2}},
  {key: "B", value: {count:10}},
  {key: "C", value: {count:4}},
]

const sortedArray = myArray.sort((a, b) => b.value.count - a.value.count);

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: i believe OP wants the result in descending order so expanding on your answer she can reverse it by using sortedArray.reverse().

Comment: I want the answers for crossfilter actually. Please check my latest post.

Comment: @NishitaSinha what do you mean exactly by crossfilter?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const groupP = [
  {key: "A", value: {count:2}},
  {key: "B", value: {count:10}},
  {key: "C", value: {count:4}},
]

const sortedGroupP = groupP.sort((a, b) => a.value.count - b.value.count);

console.log(sortedGroupP[groupP.length -2]);
console.log(sortedGroupP[groupP.length - 1]);
```

Comment: I want the answers for crossfilter actually. Please check my latest post.

Comment: @NishitaSinha I didn't get, what do you mean by cross filter ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myArray = [
  { key: "A", value: { count: 2 } },
  { key: "B", value: { count: 10 } },
  { key: "C", value: { count: 4 } },
];

const result = myArray.sort((a, b) => b.value.count - a.value.count).splice(0, 2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey thanks. It works for js, but I want the answers for crossfilter actually. Please check my latest post.